# ElasticSearch: script inline subtract dates

Tags: java, elasticsearch

Here is one of my documents in elasticsearch:

```
{
            "_index": "2017-10-21",
            "_type": "cat",
            "_id": "14",
            "_score": 2.2335923,
            "_source": {
                "name": "Biscuit",
                "breed": "Persian",
                "age": "3",
                "purchase_date": "2017-11-11T10:16:18+0100",
                "birth_date": "2017-01-21T10:16:18+0100"
            }
}
```

I would like to calculate the time between 'purchase_date' and 'birth_date' (by subtracting them) in minutes or days for example and add a new field 'age_when_bought' with this time (in every document where the breed is "Persian", but that's not the point here). It should be something like that:

```
POST /*/_update_by_query

{
    "script" : {
        "inline": "ctx._source.age_when_bought = ctx._source.purchase_date - ctx._source.birth_date"
    },
    "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "match": {
                "breed": "Persian"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work in that way. I have an error 500 with that response:

```
"caused_by": {
            "type": "class_cast_exception",
            "reason": "Cannot apply [-] operation to types [java.lang.String] and [java.lang.String]."
        }
```

I have already tried to convert those fields into dates but I might not use the good function to do it:

```
'SimpleDateFormat.parse(ctx._source.purchase_date)'
```

I still have an error 500 with that response this time:

```
"caused_by": {
            "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
            "reason": "Unknown call [parse] with [1] arguments on type [SimpleDateFormat]."
        }
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have finally found a solution!

```
POST /*/_update_by_query

{
    "script" : {
        "inline": "ctx._source.age_when_bought = (new SimpleDateFormat(\"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:sszzz\").parse(ctx._source.purchase_date).getTime()
- new SimpleDateFormat(\"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:sszzz\").parse(ctx._source.birth_date).getTime())"
    },
    "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "match": {
                "breed": "Persian"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
    }
}
```

SimpleDateFormat is a class for formatting and parsing dates in a locale-sensitive manner. It allows for formatting (date -> text), parsing (text -> date), and normalization.

The Date.getTime() method returns how many milliseconds have passed since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT.

So, by doing `date_1.getTime() - date_2.getTime()` the result will be the time between the date_1 and the date_2 in milliseconds (assuming that date_1 is closer from the current date than date_2. Otherwise, the result might be the same but negative).

Comment: Hello, I have tried your syntax but getting error `"type": "parsing_exception",    "reason": "Unknown key for a START_OBJECT in [script]."`

My code is `GET json-2019.07.30/_search
{
    "script" : {
    "inline": "ctx._source.ageOfRecord = (new SimpleDateFormat(\"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:sszzz\").parse(ctx._source.@timestamp).getTime() - new SimpleDateFormat(\"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:sszzz\").parse(ctx._source.@timestamp).getTime())"
  },
  "query": { "match_all": {} }`